# What does "unspecialized class template can't be used as a template argument" mean?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I have a class called AbstractRManagers which i would like to inheritent from a singleton template class Singleton but the abstractRmanager needing to be a template class I have come across some strange error codes that provide no use, Ive tried looking it up but to no luck.

```
template <class Type>
class AbstractRManagers : public Singleton<AbstractRManagers>
{
```

> error C3203: 'AbstractRManagers' : unspecialized class template can't
>   be used as a template argument for template parameter 'Type', expected
>   a real type

Comment: "abstract... managers... singleton..." My eyes! You probably want `class AbstractRManagers : public Singleton<AbstractRManagers<Type> >`.

Comment: Whats so bad with that? "abstract... managers... singleton..." My eyes!

Comment: It sounds like a recurring joke we have in the C++ lounge.

Comment: Very well, how do you propose I design it?

Comment: @ChrisCondy: I doubt anybody can give reasonable advice about how to design something with no idea of what you're trying to accomplish. At first glance, it there does seem to have a bit of the "Enterprise Java Hello World" flavor though.

Comment: I wouldn't know, I have no idea what you're designing, and I don't know what you mean with "manager" and "singleton". It might not be that bad.  It could just be a sign that you should name your classes better. For example, "manager" doesn't carry an obvious meaning: everyone uses it to mean something different. And some people use "singleton" to mean "one default global instance" (like `std::cout` is "the default instance" of `std::ostream`), and not the GoF idea of a singleton.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`AbstractRManagers` names a template, which isn't a type -- it has to have a template parameter give to become a type. At least if I understand what you want, you probably need something like:

```
template <class Type>
class AbstractRManagers : public Singleton<AbstractRManagers<Type> >
```

...which starts to look suspiciously CRTP-like.

Then the obligatory note: chances are pretty good that you don't really need or want a singleton here (or nearly anywhere).

Comment: I think your answer doesn't really address the heart of the issue. Note that you don't need to provide the arguments when you're *inside* the class, so it's not at all clear (to me, anyway) why the requirement is still there in the inheritance list.

Answer (score 5):

It should be `public Singleton<AbstractRManagers<Type> >` as `AbstractRManagers` is a template you need to provide the concrete type to instantiate it.